# How to get tls extensions in my go code for tls ja3 with latest golang version

Tags: go, tls1.3

this is the tls clienthelloinfo stucrt

```
type ClientHelloInfo struct {
    CipherSuites []uint16
    ServerName string
    SupportedCurves []CurveID
    SupportedPoints []uint8
    SignatureSchemes []SignatureScheme
    SupportedProtos []string
    SupportedVersions []uint16  
    Conn net.Conn
    config *Config
    ctx context.Context
}
```

this is no extensions field

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZe89.png)

how can i get tls extensions,thanks?

Comment: JA3 TLS fingerprinting will presumably be soon be available with `Extensions []uint16` exposing the list of IDs of the extensions presented by the client
 in the client hello to GetCertificate.  See the notes and the commits from 5 days ago: https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/471396. If you can't wait, a patched stdlib might be a possibility, but usually you want to avoid that.

Comment: 是的，我也看到了相关的代码，那还是再等等吧