# Get TLS Fingerprint JA3 in Golang on a request

Tags: go, fingerprint

After a long prospection on the internets I didn't find any way to get a TLS fingerprint in Golang.

The interceptor to fetch `ClientHelloInfo` doesn't provide the mandatory `Extensions` field necessary to compute JA3 fingerprint (explained on [Salesforce article](https://engineering.salesforce.com/tls-fingerprinting-with-ja3-and-ja3s-247362855967/#:%7E:text=The%20JA3S%20method%20is%20to,each%20value%20in%20each%20field.)).
Example:

```
hs := &http.Server{
        Addr:    address,
        Handler: handler,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            GetCertificate: func(info *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
                return nil, nil
            },
        },
    }
```

Is there any way to fetch this `ClientHelloInfo` with extension on the fly during an HTTPS request?
Do we have also any ways to compute JA3S?

Comment: See comments about soon to be available on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610940/how-to-get-tls-extensions-in-my-go-code-for-tls-ja3-with-latest-golang-version. See also https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32936#issuecomment-1637032504 for a possible hack to access the raw ClientHello.